# Why do I have to specify both 'runtime' and 'compile' for the same dependency?

Tags: configuration, dependency-management, gradle

I am depending on a few artifacts that I need to both compile and run my application.

According to the Gradle docs, the runtime configuration *extends* the compile configuration, so surely adding a dependency using `runtime` implies an implicit `compile` dependency?

At least that was my assumption, but it does not work. When just depending on the artifact using `runtime`, my project does not compile anymore. I literally have to:

```
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
runtime 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
```

for the application to both compile *and* see the Signpost classes at runtime.

Am I missing something? That just doesn't look right...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Almost right. Runtime configuration, indeed, *extends* compile configuration ([docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management)). It means, that any dependency added to *compile* configuration is available in *runtime* configuration ([docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom)).

`compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'` will be enough to get this artifact in both, runtime and compile.

Comment: I see -- how odd. Just trying to understand how this works then. Looking at http://www.gradle.org/0.9.1/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management, does that mean that any configuration in figure 20.2 is a combination of all the configurations that have inbound arrows to it? Thinking of 'extension' in the classic 'inheritance' kind of way, one would assume the opposite.

Comment: Oh and: is it correct to assume then that Gradle's 'runtime' configuration corresponds to Maven's 'provided' scope?

Comment: In the userguide diagram 20.2 any configuration is a combination of all the *outbound* paths, e.g. `testRuntime` includes everything from `runtime` and `compile`, beacuse outbound arrow shows that `testRuntime` extends `runtime`

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too, but by following that same logic, `runtime` would include the `compile` configuration, not vice versa. That's exactly the opposite from what you said in your answer!

Comment: Oh snap, I think I get it now. I think my mistake was that I was thinking of configurations as being "behavior" instead of being "sets". The word "extends" got me confused. Extending here actually means "superset-of". So if I add something to `compile`, then it will also be visible to anything relying on `runtime`, since it's a super-set of `compile`. Adding something only to runtime, will therefore not be visible to any task using the `compile` configuration. Does that make sense?

Comment: Great, you got the idea! Maybe, I was not clear enough in my response )

Comment: no no, I think I'm just not in my best shape at the moment... cheers again for all your help.

Comment: [GRADLE-784](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRADLE-784) has a 'provided' workaround solution.

Comment: lol, Matthias, first I shared your confusion. Now after a cup of coffee, I don't understand your confusion. For some reason everything is really confusing =) But speaking from my latest point in mind, if B extends A, then B is-a A and everything in A is visible in B - not the other way around. So if compile is A, and runtime is B, then all artifacts available in compile is available in runtime, not the other way around. Thus, what I am trying to say is, what is all that talk about "behavior" and supersets? Gradle's version of extends is the same as object oriented languages?

Comment: oh now I get it! Your question was why do we need to add stuff into compile, if runtime is supposed to "extend" compile. To summarize for other people still being confused: All dependencies added to compile **is** available in runtime, because runtime "extends" compile. But, if you follow the second link in Nikitas answer above, it is clear that we speak not of class inheritance, we speak of a reference to a real `Set`. In order for runtime to see the dependencies of compile, then the dependencies have to first be added to compile which is exactly what Matthias original question is all about.